# Sybase IQ Hierarchical query

Tags: sap-iq

I am facing an issue in Sybase IQ.I have a requirement to identify tables/views under a given view, recursively. I am trying to make use of sysdependencies. What are the options to do this?

Comment: The `sysdependencies` table is the way to go indeed and I can help you. But first, what do you mean by "recursively", and if this what I think, how do you expect the result ? Please show a data sample

Comment: What I meant was, the view can be based on another view as well as a table. Sometimes from both. So, my requirement was when I give the name of view, say 'A', the query should bring me the ultimate child tables used under it, not the intermediate/immediate children.